# Don't see some utf8 characters on android chrome browser

Tags: android, google-chrome, utf-8, google-fonts

I have simple page - http://skchbk.foxnet.pl/ encoded to UTF8 with few greek characters:

> ὁ ἄγγελος . τοῦ ἀγγέλο,messenger . angel 
>   ὁ ἀδελφός . τοῦ ἀδελφοῦ,brother 
>   ἀλλά,but . except 
>   ὁ ἄνθρωπος . τοῦ ἀνθρώπου,man

this page look good on windows, but on android phone/tablet with google chrome browser I don't see characters like

> ἀ

I found somewhere information that on android font's are not handling some UTF8 characters, so I used google fonts - and greek font - https://fonts.google.com/specimen/GFS+Didot -  but still on android I see "[]" instead of few characters.

Do you know why android has problem with fonts/encoding? Am I missing some configuration of google fonts?

---

EDIT:

I tried different approach and I used google-webfonts-helper tool - https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/gfs-didot?subsets=greek - to download eot, woff, woff2, ttf, svg files, and I changed CSS code to

```
<style>
@font-face {
    font-family: 'GFS Didot';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: local('GFS Didot Regular'), local('GFSDidot-Regular'),
    url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
    url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../fonts/gfs-didot-v7-greek-regular.svg#GFSDidot') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
body {
    font-family: 'GFS Didot', serif;
}
```

but the result is the same... I still see rectangles on mobile chrome

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm also looking to see Greek characters, and they show correctly on desktop Firefox/Chrome and mobile Firefox, but no dice on Chrome for Mobile.